# Mouse scroll wheel causing text selection in VS code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS code and by accident I pressed some keys and somehow the scroll wheel of the mouse is selecting text rather than scrolling the page up and down. I feel like the mouse wheel press is acting like pressing the "alt" key.

I've tried deleting VS code and deleting extensions and such and it didn't work.
The problem persists only in VS code.

Is that problem familiar to you?

Do you know how to fix that?

Thank you, Ori Silberman.

Comment: Can you show us your `keybindings.json` file? Press Ctrl+K Ctrl+S and then click the file with an arrow icon in the top right corner.

Comment: @D.Pardal - Hi, at the moment it's empty.

Comment: In that case I don't know what's causing the wheel to select text. It never happened to me.

Comment: It's as if pressing the wheel is pressing the "alt" key. It's so weird.Do you have suggestions what can I do or where can I ask for help?

Comment: I don't, sorry.

Comment: the only help I can give is to completely nuke your VS code, and all preferences and support files and start again.

Answer (score 0):

The only help I can give is to completely nuke your VS code, and all preferences and support files and start again.

The preferences and support files can be found as follows.

macOS:

- `~/Library/Application Support/Code`

Windows:

- `%APPDATA%\Code\`

Linux:

- `~/.config/Code/`

Comment: Hey, I'm using windows. What are the equivalent steps?

Comment: @TuxedoJoe didn't work how? If completely nuking your install settings didn't get your mouse working it implies your problem is not in VSCode.

Comment: @MattSephton, you might be very right. I'm using a ThinkPad TrackPoint keyboard keyboard and trying to get my scroll+nipple to work. It keeps highlighting the text. Wondered if this could be a VSCode thing since it works in all other apps.